# Passing dynamic QueryParams in Mapper.findAll

Tags: scala, lift

I have a function like this:

```
def getList(gig: Gig, createdBy: User = null, all: Boolean = true): List[Bid] = {
    var bys = List[QueryParam](By(Bid.gig, gig))
    if (createdBy!=null) bys = By(Bid.createdBy, createdBy) :: bys
    if (!all) bys = By(Bid.deleted, false) :: bys

    Bid.findAll(bys) //gives error as do not accept List[QueryParam]
  }
```

How do I supply dynamic number of QueryParams to findAll?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Bid.findAll(bys:_*)
```

Side note: It's worth avoiding `null` in favor or `Option`.

```
def getList(gig: Gig, createdBy: Option[User] = None, all: Boolean = true): List[Bid] = {
```

Then you can do

```
val bys = (if (!all) Some(By(Bid.deleted, false)) else None) ++
          (createdBy.map(u => By(Bid.createdBy, u))) ++ 
          List[QueryParam](By(Bid.gig, gig))
Bid.findAll(bys:_*)
```